# Running GUI program on linux machine using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to run open a GUI program on a remote Ubuntu machine using ssh.

I want to open, lets say Firefox or Skype, on a machine I have connected to via ssh.
But when writing logging in with user2 and writing `sudo -u user1 firefox` I get an error message saying no display specified.

The machine is turned on and logged in with user1, it just appears that i cant get ubuntu to recognize that there is a GUI available.

I wouldnt mind alternative solutions but I would prefer help with this specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Set `X11Forwarding yes` in configuration file for SSH server (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`). Restart server and run `ssh` on client machine with `-X` or `-Y` option (this should work with OpenSSH).

Comment: I forgot to mention that i want the program GUI to launch on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbus-launch firefox&
```

This has worked for me in the past from a shell, you could give it a try via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

The use of sudo complicates things a bit and will require a few extra steps.

If you've setup your /etc/ssh/sshd_config as others have mentioned with

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

then ssh'n into the box as user2 via

```
$ ssh -YC remote.example.com
```

You should be able to run remote X apps as user2.  A simple way to test this on a lot of X based systems is to run

```
$ xlogo
```

It's very lightweight compared to something like firefox though firefox will work as well.

Once you are certain X is working via your remote ssh connection as user2 we can make it work with the sudo to user1.  The problem is that when you sudo to user1 you are losing authority to use your remote X forwarding.  To get around this, first as user2 do the following after logging in

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:17.0
$ xauth list
<snip>
carlisle/unix:17  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  161bda5fc81200a4e74e578009177fb8
```

You should see a line that contains the same display number, in my example it's 17.  You'll want to find the matching number in the xauth list output.  Next sudo to user1 and run an xauth add command to add the auth line that matched above

```
$ sudo su - user1
$ xauth add carlisle/unix:17  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  161bda5fc81200a4e74e578009177fb8
```

You should now be able to run any app you want.

```
$ xlogo  # or any X app such as firefox
```

If you get an error about being unable to lock ~user2/.Xauthority you will need to adjust permissions on that file prior to using sudo to switch to user1.  It's not exactly secure but you could set the file permissions to chmod 666 on that file to test.